# glibc detected free() invalid pointer

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of trouble with some dynamic memory allocation.

Below is just a test code that I've been playing around with to try and fix the problem (it's the same problem in my current project's code, this is just a simpler way to show it).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main(){

    int x = 5;
    int *ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    ptr = &x;

    printf("x = %d\n",x);

    *ptr = 3;
    printf("x = %d\n",x);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine and when run I get the correct outputs printed "x = 5 x = 3"
But then I get the error:

```
glibc detected  ./dnam: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfccf698
```

dnam is the name of the test program.
From what I've read about the error, it's supposedly caused by freeing memory that you haven't malloc/calloc/realloc'd.

This error message is followed by a backtrace and a memory map. AT the end of the memory map I'm told the program has aborted (core dumped).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
   int *ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

   ptr = &x;
```

You are changing `ptr` value! The compiler will be taking unlimited revenge if you attempt to free it.

Here:

```
free(ptr);
```

You are `free`-ing an object not allocated through `malloc`.

Comment: I am? I had copied this code from an example and then tweaked it to use malloc and free.

Comment: @user2985302 but then `free` would attempt to free `x`, not the object allocated by `malloc`. Why are you using `malloc` and `free`, you don't need them here.

Comment: So in this case I would not need to free ptr at the end of the program?

Comment: Righto, thank you very much. I missed the lecture on Dynamic Memory Allocation and evidently the slides wasn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory and saving its address into ptr. Then, you make ptr point to x's address, thus when you run `free(ptr)` you essentially freeing `&x`, which doesn't work.

tl;dr: there's no need for `malloc` and `free` when you're assigning the pointer a pointer to another var.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use this code.I think you should use a temp pointer save the init ptr.at last free(temp).like this:

```
 int *temp = ptr;


  free(temp);
```